# how to get token value in NuxtAuth v.4?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

how can i get token value in NuxtAuth v.4.9 ?
i have used this code
[image]

and tis code give me this in console .
[image]

BUT i cant get token if i write

```
  var token = this.$auth.$storage._state._token.local
```

so , How can i get Token Value ??
also , how can i get rid of that lint error ?

Comment: Have you tried this? https://auth.nuxtjs.org/api/tokens `_state` seems to be a private field not to be read from.

Comment: yes and i think this is for v.5

Comment: You should probably use v5 here.

Comment: Btw, you do have it in your localStorage/cookie too no?